# How to remove member from viber group

Tags: viber-messenger

How can i remove a member of a group which do not have admin. Admin left Viber and i have mistakenly added wrong guy. I and other members tried but we could not remove him. how can i remove him.

Answer (score 1):

[Viber Support page](http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1476543-how-do-i-use-group-conversations-on-my-android-device-?b_id=3838#.U99rZICSw8o) mentions this:

> Removing participants from a group
>   Participants cannot remove other participants from a group. Each participant can choose to exit the group at any time.

So it seems like your only choice is to exit the group and start a new one.